# download failed, couldn't connect to host

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I haven't been able to install new plugins or updating plugins after upgrading to wordpress 4.3 on my Ubuntu Server 12.04.5 32bit machine. Usually I could just do it by clicking on the "update" link that's associated with a specific plugin. And it will update it successfully with less than a minute. But this time, it took so long and at the end, it threw out error "download failed, couldn't connect to host".

Then, I thought and guessed that it might be to do with the new wordpress 4.3. So I downgraded it back to previous version 4.2.4 and tried to update the plugin that needs updating. It also took so long and in the end, gave the same error message.

The strange thing is that I haven't made any changes to my Ubuntu server in terms of firewall at all.

My installed PHP version is 5.5.25 and apache is 2.4.12.

The permission of my wp-config.php is 644.

I don't know what else to look. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

did you install the correct .dll files in system directory? uninstall the program and try running a system repair and .dll file patcher

Comment: Thank you Isaiah. Sorry, this is not on a windows platform. I don't think there is any .dll file on Ubuntu Server. .dll files are only found in Windows OS. Please correct me if I'm wrong.